# Remove space after new line

Tags: tex-core

I need to remove the space inserted by starting a new line in tex file. Exmple:

file.tex:

```
This is actually a paragraph
that will continue to this new line.
```

file.pdf

```
This is actually a paragraph that will continue to this new line.
                            ^
             I would like to remove this space
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a `%` after the end of the first line will cancel that space and join the two words `paragraph` and `that`.

```
This is actually a paragraph% <--- This will suppress the spacing
that will continue to this new line.
```

> [image]

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate.

Comment: Being a very basic question, I guess very likely yes, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this for a long piece of text you could define a simple switch that makes new line characters be ignored:

```
\def\ignorelinebreaks{%
  \catcode`\^^M=9
  \endlinechar=`\^^M}
```

then use it with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ignorelinebreaks{%
  \catcode`\^^M=9
  \endlinechar=`\^^M}

\begin{document}

{
\ignorelinebreaks
hello world
world hello
}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

You can even exploit LaTeX's environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ignorelinebreaks{%
  \catcode`\^^M=9
  \endlinechar=`\^^M}

\begin{document}

\begin{ignorelinebreaks}
  hello world
  world hello
\end{ignorelinebreaks}

\end{document}
```